# Docker swarm Kafka. How to assign unique host for brokers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-swarm

Hi I'm trying to run kafka with unique broker hosts for each node

the main goal is to make sure that after restarting the Kafka service, broker hosts do not change

i try to do something like this

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
       - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.5.0
    hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    deploy:
      mode: global
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 9094:9094
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID_COMMAND:   "{{.Node.ID}} | grep -o '[0-9]$$+'"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://localhost:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://{{.Node.Hostname}}:9092,OUTSIDE://:9094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181

  web-socket-service:
    image: 'my_hub/web_socket_service'
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
    environment:
      BOOTSTRAP_SEVER: '{{.Node.Hostname}}:9092'
```

for the test i am using two nodes
[image]

Kafka runs well on both nodes, but then i get this error on one of these nodes

```
WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1002] Error connecting to node worker1:9092 (id: 1002 rack: null) (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
dev_kafka.0.wxl6rlfypaai@main    | java.net.UnknownHostException: worker1: Name does not resolve
```

Perhaps this is due to the Hostname field in the Kafka service, maybe there is some other approach

grateful for any help

Comment: Seems to me like your overlay network doesn't have a DNS server. Overall, I'd suggest using Strimzi Kafka operator in Kubernetes where this is already a solved problem rather than mucking with node variables in Swarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to docker 20.10 on all your swarm nodes. One of the features that made this kind of deployment possible was docker 20.10 does add the container hostname to the docker network dns aliases, where 19.03 does not.

Comment: Thanks for your help this works as expected but another problem appeared, after restarting kafka I am getting this error ```2 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener```, You may have experienced this how it can be fixed?

Comment: If they both started on the same node, you might need to set `max_replicas_per_node`.

Comment: didn't help, just to be sure I ran swarm with one replica of the service, but still have this error.
Strange as if the listeners were left with the old brokers

Comment: hmmm, with mode:global is `{{.Node.ID}}` stable between updates? Its a large hash. Its only a simple integer value in mode: replicated.

Comment: Yes, its not nice solution replaced with this ```hostname -I | awk -F '' '{print $$ 1}' | awk -F '.' '{print $$ 4}' ```
didn't help, maybe it is impossible to implement with swarm

Comment: try mode: replicated, replicas: 2